# How to find groups of users with the same applications?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

Straight off the bat here I just want to apologies for the formatting below... it's starting to get a little late here and I'm going a little blurry eye'd looking at this all day.

This has been bugging me for a couple of days now, I need to be able to find a group of users that have the same applications installed on their PC.

Firstly, have a look at the tables below...

```
ApplicationName UserName
App1            Tom
App2            Tom
App3            Tom
App5            Gerry
App6            Gerry
App7            Gerry
App1            Peter
App2            Peter
App3            Peter
App4            Peter
App1            Joe
App2            Joe
App4            Joe
App5            Mark
App5            Tony
App6            Jessy
```

What I need to get at the end of this is a group of users who have the same apps.... for example
Group1:  Tom, Peter, Joe (because they have a combination of app1 -> 4)

Group2:  Gerry, Mark, Tony, Jessy (because they have a combination of app5 -> 7)

Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Could you post what you would like the output to look like?

Comment: Joe does not have the same apps as Tom and Peter ( {1,2,3} vs {1,2,4} ) if there is some logical connection between the apps, create a AppGroup column and then you can select based on the group.

Comment: How do you determine a combination? 2 apps? 3 apps? 4 apps?

Comment: You should show us what your SQL statement attempt looks like. SO works best when you show us what you've tried and we can show you were it may be failing.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments are pointing out, you didn't specify what the answer should look like, but here's some SQL to help:

```
with data as 
(
select distinct a.UserName,
stuff((select ','+ApplicationName 
       from Table1 as b 
       where b.UserName=a.UserName 
       for xml path('')),1,1,'') as Applications
from Table1 as a
)
select Applications, count(*) from data
group by Applications
;
```

In a fiddle with the sample data here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f7b37/5